# I'm having trouble integrating VS2012 with Git

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, credentials

I have a Secure Git repository with my company and I want to integrate Git into VS2012. However, I'm not able to clone my repository from Team Forge. When I grab my ssh key and enter it when cloning, I get an error saying that I don't have permission to my account and I may not have entered the correct credentials. However, I was never prompted for my credentials. Is there a place to add my credentials in VS2012?

I also saw some posts saying that VS2012 doesn't support ssh so I also tried using my http key with no luck

Comment: VS 2012 does not have Git support out-of-the-box; which Git plug-in are you using?  (The Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Git plug-in does not have support for SSH.)

Comment: yes, I'm using the MVS tools for Git plug-in. And since it doesn't support SSH I'm just using my http key

Comment: @RDoolabh if you don't get an answer that helps you fix this for Visual Studio, consider using git from the command line instead.

Comment: that's what I'm using now which is fine. However, the visual studios integration is extremely robust and highlights changes you've made. It also allows for easier file merging (or so I'm told)

Comment: I've tried a few integrations with VS and find them pretty slow/unproductive. Conflict resolution real easy with tools like BeyondCompare. Just my opinion of course.

Answer (score 0):

**Generate a public / private key pair:**

```
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

The public key will be in your home directory. i.e. usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

**Add your public ssh key to TeamForge:**

```
$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Paste the contents of the public key into My Settings > Authorized keys.

**Test the connection:**

```
$ ssh -v user@server
```

**Clone the repository:**

Also, make sure you are cloning with ssh, not https.

i.e. `$ git clone ssh://user@server/project.git`

Comment: I was able to generate a public key. However, when I paste it into the Authorized keys, I get a message saying that the key was rejected. Should I be pasting the whole key fingerprint which is shown in my git bash? (the long string of letters and numbers followed by my user@server)

Comment: Yes the whole thing. Did you enter a password when generating the key pair or just left it blank? Try opening the public key file in notepad and copying from there. Perhaps was an issue with line endings or something when copying from git bash.

Comment: I did not create a passphrase when prompted. But I'll try pasting the key from notepad

Comment: ok, I was able to successfully save my key. However, when I tested the connection as you said, it said connection refused. Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps try user = git instead. Does the clone not work either? Otherwise I think you have to follow these steps: https://git.help.collab.net/entries/24127827-TeamForge-Git-integration-General-usage-FAQ Add the config to user and email. i.e. `$ git config --global user.name "<TeamForge username>"`